# Intra-class correlation between two raters

Tags: agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I'm reading a paper that compares two raters (one human, one algorithm) that rate images with a single number (total volume of an object in the image), and there are about 100 images. Each image is an MRI of a different patient, all with a similar disease. They have used a two-way mixed model (absolute) to measure ICC, but I think I'm having a little trouble understanding the big picture, as my background is not strong in statistics, and I'm trying to understand how this experiment relates to this definition of ICC:

$Y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_{j} + \epsilon_{ij}$

My understanding is that there are two "groups", and 100 observations in each group. Are these observations exchangeable? Why? I would have assumed that the data would be paired across the groups because they are rating the same image, which I thought would have made them non-exchangeable.

I know this model is trying to account for variance across the group, as well as variance due to the rater, and some other noise term... so how do I actually interpret ICC in this context? Someone else described it elsewhere (I can't find the link now) as the percent of "relevant" variance. What does that mean?